# Define dynamically what columns to update in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have this jOOQ example that could either update COLUMN_A or COLUMN_B

```
context.update(MY_TABLE)
        .set(MY_TABLE.COLUMN_A, fieldA)
        .where(MY_TABLE.SK.eq(sk))
        .execute();


context.update(MY_TABLE)
        .set(MY_TABLE.COLUMN_B, fieldB)
        .where(MY_TABLE.SK.eq(sk))
        .execute();
```

I want to have a *single* code instead of two snippets, how to extract the `.set` portion into a variable to be able to do that? Something along these lines:

```
if (option == 1)
    setColumn = `(MY_TABLE.COLUMN_A, fieldA)`;
else
    setColumn = `(MY_TABLE.COLUMN_B, fieldB)`;


context.update(MY_TABLE)
        .set(setColumn)
        .where(MY_TABLE.SK.eq(sk))
        .execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all expressions share the same data type, do this:

```java
context.update(MY_TABLE)
        .set(option == 1 ? MY_TABLE.COLUMN_A : MY_TABLE.COLUMN_B,
             option == 1 ? fieldA : fieldB)
        .where(MY_TABLE.SK.eq(sk))
        .execute();
```

If you can't do this in a type safe way, you could use rawtype casts, or omit type safety using a `Map`:

```java
context.update(MY_TABLE)
        .set(option == 1 
           ? Map.of(MY_TABLE.COLUMN_A, fieldA) 
           : Map.of(MY_TABLE.COLUMN_B, fieldB))
        .where(MY_TABLE.SK.eq(sk))
        .execute();
```